# global variable is different in different functions

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-2.7, global-variables

I know that using global variable in functions is wrong, but I have a code that uses these variables and I have an issue that I can't find how to solve.

I have a module with the following code:

```
messages = {}

def MessageReceived(message):
    global messages

    print messages
    msgNumber = message[0]
    if messages.has_key(msgNumber):
        messageData = messages.pop(msgNumber)
        ReleaseMessageNumber(msgNumber)
        if messageData["callback"] is not None:
            messageData["callback"](messageData["originalMessage"])

def SendMessage(message, callBack):
    global messages

    msgNumber = GetMessageNumber()

    messageToSend = msgNumber + message + "\0"

    messages[msgNumber] = { 'originalMessage' : message, 'time' : time.time(), 'callback' : callBack }
    print messages
    Send(messageToSend)

    return True
```

In general, the function "SendMessage" builds a message with a message number, sends the message an stores the message and a callback in a **global** dictionary.

The function "MessageReceived" gets the callback of the specific message from the global dictionary and calls it.

The problem is that it seems that 2 different dictionaries exists here.

When I send a message, I see that the dictionary grows (a new record is added to the dictionary every time I send a message), but the print at the "MessageReceived" function always shows an empty dictionary.

Can you help me with that? Where is the bug here?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code isn't a [MCVE] so it's not easy to test it. But the global `messages` is a list, not a dict; it should be `messages = {}`. FWIW, a better way than using a global to share data is to create a class.

Comment: Can you post a little more detail around how this is being called?  What does the `send` method do?  Are you sure you're multithreading?  If you're using multi processing then the globals won't be shared.

Comment: I hope those functions are called within a single request. Otherwise global variables make little sense (they are initialised on every request)

Comment: The use of [] instead of {} is just here. I fixed it. I removed the irrelevant parts from the code, but still included some, just in order to provide the necessary background.

Comment: The send and receive are working against a serial COM port. This code is part of a django application that initializes the serial port when it starts. The "SendMessage" function is called by django view (as result of a user request). The receive is called by another thread that infinitly reads data from the COM port.

Comment: @Pynchia that's not true, in any normal way of serving Django.

Comment: @DanielRoseman with all due respect, I have always developed under the assumption that each request could have been served by a different process. It does not appear to be the case using Django's own webserver: I have just tried and incremented a global in a view and it works, it keeps increasing on every request. Would it work with other setups? (apache/gunicorn/etc). It is not clear to me what processes are involved (webserver and wsgi server/application?)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, although it doesn't affect your problem there is no need to use the `global` keyword anywhere in this code. You never re-assign the global dicts, you only mutate them, so there is no need to declare them as global - Python finds them in the module scope anyway.

The problem though is that all module-level variables are per-process. If your receive function is always running in its own thread, it will never see any of the data from the view.

Since however you *already know* that using global variables is bad, I'm not sure why you are doing it. There are plenty of ways of passing data between processes; storing it in the database is probably the best if you're using Django.